# Select date from sql and format this to text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my database with type `date`. The name of these column is also `date`.

The format of the data in these column is: `2016-10-05` (yyyy-mm-dd). I want to SELECT the `date` for the first `id` as: `5 May 2016`.

I also want to select the date in another language.

How can I run this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is not stored as a string.  It is stored as an internal representation.  The YYYY-MM-DD format is simply how MySQL outputs the date.

If you want to format the date differently, convert it to a string using `date_format()` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)).  For your particular format:

```
select date_format(date, '%e %b %y')
```

(I should note that I personally much prefer the ANSI and ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.)

As for internationalization (support in other languages), you might want to start [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) in the documentation.

Comment: `set lc_time_names = 'nl_NL'`

Comment: when I run this it gets executed, but no results. After this I run `select date_format(date, '%e %b %y')` but I get the same output

Comment: @John . . . It works in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/62400).  I had to use October for the date, because the three-letter abbreviation is obviously different from English.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DATE_FORMAT()` :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.date,%e %b %Y)
FROM YourTable t
```

You can read all about the available formats [in this article.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)